# Android - Tab sizing and positioning

Tags: android, layout, textview

I've created my own tab control and now I'm trying to decide on sizing and positioning of the tabs.  I currently use:

android:layout_weight="9"
  android:layout_weight="1"

So that the tab buttons at the top of the screen take up 1/10th of the screen height, and I want the text only labels of my tabs to fill up half that height. I currently specify the height of the text in the TextView as follows:

android:textSize="16dp"

Which looks nice on my emulator, but I assume doesn't do what I want on various screen sizes. Can I specify the text size to be half the size of the containing TextView? (Which itself was sized correctly already by the layout_weight).

Comment: At what point is the layout finished? in onCreate() TextView.getHeight returns 0. One way I guess is to query the height after the layout then set the text size to height/2px

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9cd129eb10673e2c/c1e3a8de6bf51d5a?lnk=gst&q=View+getHeight#c1e3a8de6bf51d5a

Answer (score 0):

```
android:textSize="16dp"
```

Don't use exact pixels. If you must set a size, use `dip`

Comment: Yeah but I already have the layout giving me 1/10 screen size, 16dp doesn't have any relation to 1/10 screen size so is just as incorrect as exact pixels here.